# Transform a polynomial so that positive roots are shifted right and negative roots are shifted left

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to shift the roots of a polynomial outward, instead of to the left or right.  Its relatively simple to shift all the solutions in one direction by substituting (x-k) or (x+k) for x within the equation, but is it possible to shift all the positive solutions to the right and all the negative solutions to the left?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the answers!  I've run into the scaling method before, and I don't think it will suit my purposes here.  Specifically, I want to move all the roots away from the origin by 1.  Scaling won't work so well because different roots would need different scalings.

Comment: Well you can shift by substituting $x - k\cdot\mathrm{sgn}(x)$. It's cheating, but direct.

Comment: It is cheating, but I'll keep it in mind if I get frustrated enough with following the rules.  Thanks!

Comment: As an applied mathematician, I am wondering in which context this problem appears. It might be an "XY problem". There are some problems whose condition number depends directly on the minimum gap between positive and negative solutions, for instance computing the stable invariant subspace of a symmetric matrix. What you propose looks like a technique to improve the accuracy of the solution, and it is doomed to fail because the condition number is an unavoidable limit.

Comment: I'm poking around trying to find a nice representation for the constructible numbers (the rationals plus square root).  There are quite a few posts on the general algebraic numbers topic, but nothing that's exactly covering what I'm looking for.  This shifting has to do with addition of roots.

Comment: @JoelTurnblade Ok, nothing like what I had in mind then. :)

Answer (score 3):

Let $p(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2 z^2 + \dots + a_m z^m$ and let $z_1, \dots, z_m \in \mathbb{C}$ be the roots of $p$. For $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, set $q(z) = b_0 + b_1z + \dots + b_mz^m$, where $b_j = \lambda^{-j} a_i$. Then the zeros of $q$ are $\lambda z_1, \dots, \lambda z_m$.

Therefore if $\lambda > 0$, all roots are moved away from $0$ and if $0 < \lambda < 1$, all roots are moved closer to $0$. For $\lambda = -1$, negative roots become positive and positive roots become negative.

Answer (score 3):

You can scale the polynomial.

For instance, if $r$ is a root of $p(x)$, then $2r$ is a root of $p(x/2)$, which shifts positive right and negative left (and imaginary more along the corresponding direction).